# Performance Testing for Japanese Language Based website

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, multilingual, loadrunner, cjk

I have an application in which the content inside the website is totally in **Japanese language** with some english alphabets included in between.

Example string- **ﾍﾏﾄｸﾘｯﾄ A B C ﾍﾏﾄｸﾘｯﾄ**

Need to Capture string- **A B C** or **ﾍﾏﾄｸﾘｯﾄ**

How to capture the value for text check/Assertions using LR? Or any other tool is recommended for Multi Lingual Web Testing?

Answer (score 0):

1. In case if you are passing via CSV data set config set encode type as gb2312 or SHIFT-JIS
2. Please go through below link incase if you want to convert
   https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/changing-jmeter-language/
3. If you want to do  correlation, boundaries are same, it is better either by using regular expression extractor or boundary extractor